# Optimizing a repetiton

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a small Menu strip item where I have a plethora of buttons which activate different forms.

The code for one button would be this:

```
    Form B1 = new Form1();
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (B1.Visible == false)
            {
                B1 = new Form1();
            }

            B1.Visible = true;
            B1.Activate();
        }
```

I also have  a mouse enter- and leave event:

```
  private void Button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Text = "Something prdy intriguing";
    }
    private void Button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Text = "Hi";
    }
```

And a tooltip:

```
private void Tooltips()
{
ToolTip forB1 = new ToolTip();
forB1.SetToolTip(button1, "21.11.17");
}
```

Now imagine i need about 8 buttons for 8 different forms, that means i have to repeat all of these again and a gain, wasting time AND taking up a LOT of code space.

Is it possible to compress these in anyway?
This is very out of my world, im unsure where to start optimizing.

Comment: you can do this many different ways in regards to the menuItems for example point them all to the same event handler, use a switch() {case: } to check the meunitem name and build from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is move all this to one function:

```
public void AttachMenuStripButtonHandlers(
    Button btn, 
    Form form, 
    string enterText,
    string leaveText,
    string tooltip) {

    btn.Click += (sender, args) => {
        form.Visible = true;
        form.Activate();
    };
    btn.MouseEnter += (sender, args) => {
        btn.Text = enterText;
    };
    btn.MouseLeave += (sender, args) => {
        btn.Text = leaveText;
    };
    new ToolTip().SetToolTip(btn, tooltip);
}
```

And for each button call like this:

```
AttachMenuStripButtonHandlers(Button1, B1, "on enter", "on leave", "tooltip");
```

Comment: Just for clarification, you are saying that the AttachMenuStripButtonHandlers method would need to be called for each button in the constructor of the form?

Comment: @MoonMoo wherever author is doing this now. If he is doing this in form designer then yes - in constructor of the form.

Comment: Hmm indeed this works but your click function isn't working exactly right, you can essentially open new form but upon closing or disposing that form you cant open it anymore, you have to give over its type i think ..

Comment: @Flame well I hope you can adjust this code a bit to achieve your goal. It's just an example of how you cn reduce code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

For second part of your question, You could do something like this

```
private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).Text = "Something prdy intriguing";
}
private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).Text = "Hi";
}
```

You need to attach same event handler to all buttons.

Comment: Hmm, this is a good solution but i actually feel like this part overall isn't very flexible for optimizing, since if i want different text for every button i'd still need to repeat it, but is there possibly a way to write it into a function? like button1.mouseEnter.text = "this and that" ? this would mean i wouldnt need to travel to the designer to release the event

Comment: You could keep your custom text object in button's tag property and pull it in event handlers. Something like this  - button1.Tag=(EnterText="My enter text", LeaveText="My leave text").

Answer (score 0):

So i am kinda stealing @Evk's code here but essentially this works the way I wanted to.

```
public void ButtonHandlers(Type NewForm)
    {

            NewButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Form TheNewMain = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(NewForm);
                if (TheNewMain.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    TheNewMain.Activate();
                }
            };
```

Essentially what i added was instead of getting the Form i have to get the type, since what I want is that when a form is Visible, it won't open it twice, going by Evks code it opens it yes but upon close it's disposed and it cant create a new instance of it.

In code i just have to ask for `typeof(formName)` in as `NewForm`

Thanks Evk!